# Ruby on Rails symbol validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have this model:

```
class Story < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_presence_of :name , :link
end
```

Where a validation for a form take place. But I want also to validate if the string "http" is included in the :link symbol. I can't do :link.include? because :link is symbol. How do I do that?

My View is this:

```
<% form_for :story do |f| %>
<p>
  name:<br />
  <%=f.text_field :name %>
</p>
<p>
  link:<br />
  <%= f.text_field :link %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= submit_tag :"submit this story" %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: "So I have this controler" should be "So I have this model" ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you add in a [validates_format_of](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#M002168) you can supply a regex to test the link with.

```
class Story < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_presence_of :name , :link
    validates_format_of :link, :with => /^http.*$/
end
```

Answer (score 1):

> ...in the :link symbol. I can't do :link.include? because :link is symbol.

Just so it's clear, note that `:link` (as a symbol) is just a way to pass the *name* of the `link` method, in this case telling the validation which methods it should work on. If you want to value returned by `link` (which would presumably be the link attribute of the object), you would call `link` as a normal method. For validations, however, Peter's answer is what you want.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I said I can't use .include? on a :symbol, it's not possible. Thank you for trying to help the helpless noob.